# Protractor: Storing URL in a variable to parse returns "undefined"

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I've been trying to get the current URL and am wanting to cut out parts of the URL to use in another method. 
I've tried many ways, and one solution I saw online suggested using the `beforeEach()` method. I've been trying this and no matter what, `this.urlString` always returns undefined.

Heres what i current have. I must be missing something as to why this is returning undefined however I can't figure it out.

```
this.urlString;

beforeEach(function () {
  mainPO.navigateHome();
  mainPO.clickCurrent();

  browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
    return this.urlString = url;
  });
});

console.log(this.urlString)
```

What I want to do is store the URL in a string, then parse the string to cut out everything before the ".com" of the URL so i can take the string and plug it into another URL for crawling to another link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get URL value as a string, you need to *resolve a promise returned by `browser.getCurrentUrl()` function call*:

```
beforeEach(function () {
  mainPO.navigateHome();
  mainPO.clickCurrent();

  this.urlString = browser.getCurrentUrl();
});

this.urlString.then(function (url) {
    console.log(url);
});
```

Comment: If i use this, would i be able to call this.urlString to retrieve the URL? Or do i need to stick this in another method to call?


In essence instead of console.log(url), I am using url.split(".com").pop() to remove the .com and everything before in the URL so i can plug the result into another object.

Comment: @user249656 yes, but you should always keep in mind that `urlString` would return you a promise which needs to be resolved.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any articles/links explaining promises and such so i understand them better?

Comment: @user249656 sure, I think this introduction is a good one: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md.

Comment: console.log(url) is also undefined.